Как сделать так, чтобы выведенное время оставалось неизменным после перезагрузки страницы
Я делаю сайт и мне нужно чтобы после клика выводилось текущее время, но после каждого обновления страницы оно меняется, как сделать так, чтобы оно оставалось неизменным?
вот код HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="year"></div>
    <div class="month"></div>
    <div class="day"></div>
    <div class="minutes"></div>
    <div class="seconds"></div>
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JS:
let year = document.querySelector('.year');
let month = document.querySelector('.month');
let hours = document.querySelector('.day');
let minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes');
let seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function allDate(){
    let time = new Date();
    year.innerHTML = time.getFullYear();
    month.innerHTML = time.getMonth() + 1;
    hours.innerHTML = time.getHours();
    seconds.innerHTML = time.getSeconds()
}

allDate();


Очевидно же, его нужно хранить в БД

для меня не очевидно)

localStorage подойдет?

все зависит от ваших целей, если вам необходимо хранить дату на сервере то не подойдет

для меня нужно чтобы она просто оставалась неизменной после обновления страницы

Можно хранить в кукис (но это не культурно), можно хранить в БД, можно обновлять кликая по кнопкам, обновляя innerHTML других контролов, можно писать на каком-нибуть JavaScript'вом фреймворкеворке. Всё зависит от архитектуры проекта/системы. Можно для браузера писать на JavaScript/TypeScript в VisualStudio Code. JavaScript фрейворки: JQuery (устарел для вашего стиля ниписания)
React Сайт-переводчик, чтобы читать документацию от производителя:
[Google Переводчик](https://translate.google.com/?

Спросите у системного архитектора вашего юрлица или директора по информационной безопасности, но если это ваша дипломная работа или вы учитесь JavaScript то делайте как хотите, но зависит от уровня безопасности сайтов.

Самое простое - localStorage(но есть ограничения).

Я проверил js и html правильный!

ребят, спасибо за ответы, но не могли бы вы скинуть пример того, как сделать это правильно через localStorage, я сижу туплю второй час, ничего не получается

@DmitriySidyakin В разметке нет элемента с классом btn, а в скрипте нет minutes... Так что я бы не говорил однозначно, что все правильно

@swaD Делал на скорую руку, исключительно для примера:)

@osqua Подключи по требованию SwaD Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/ и Наподлючай ещё кучу других Jquery UI Controls и других контролов или обратись к дизайнеру корпорации и бекендеру. В чём суть проблемы, наспостите кучу ответов, может засчитает что-то.

@DmitriySidyakin Вот ничего подобного! Где я там упоминал BootStrap и jQuery? Про jQuery уже можно забыть, а bootstrap для быстро_верстки_на_коленке вполне, но это не про сохранение данных

@osqua смело давай ответ на свой вопрос https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage ты всё знаешь, пиши свой JavaScipt Сам, а то другие тут отвлекают

Вот пример, как сохранять и доставать значения из localStorage.
Демонстрация на примере одного поля(В сниппет не обернуть, т.к. localStorage не поддерживается)
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="seconds"></div>
  <button class="btn">Новая дата</button>
</div>
  
  const seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds');
  const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

  function allDate(){
    let time = new Date();
    seconds.innerHTML = time.getSeconds();
    // Сохраняем значение
    localStorage.setItem('seconds', time.getSeconds());
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Достаем значение
    const secondSave = localStorage.getItem('seconds');
    if (secondSave) { // Если есть, отображаем
      seconds.innerHTML = secondSave;
    }
  })
  // При клике на кнопку, запустится функция
  btn.addEventListener('click', allDate);

Что происходит в скрипте:
Создается слушатель на загрузку HTML(DOMContentLoaded), как только все будет загружено, будет осуществлена попытка взять данные из localStorage и если данные есть, они будут подставлены в соответствующее поле на экране.
При вызове функции allDate, будет пересчитано значение поля, отображено на экране и сохранено в localStorage. Вызов allDate повешен на нажатие кнопки
P.S.: Для хранения множества значений, рекомендую использовать объект. Что бы ключ localStorage был один и содержал все значения.

Пожалуйста закройте вопрос, лишь у Вас достаточно прав с репутацией

@DmitriySidyakin Не понимаю, зачем закрывать данный вопрос?
